# What is the sum of Fibonacci reciprocals?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

How can I calculate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}$, where $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$ and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$?

Empirically, the result is around $3.35988566$.

Is there a "more mathematical way" to express this?

Comment: You should do something about the first term. As it is, your series starts with $\frac{1}{0}$.

Comment: @Dan Shved: Yep, thanks!

Comment: Related: [Sum of inverse of Fibonacci numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711292/sum-of-inverse-of-fibonacci-numbers)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: That question was posted 6 hours ago. You should link my question there, not the other way round.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Oh, I see you already did that... :)

Comment: @barakmanos The other question is related to this one. For the users who read your question, the link I posted in comment might be useful. I do not really see what appears to be the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [A079586](https://oeis.org/A079586), where you can find several references. It doesn't look like there is a 'nice' closed form, but some results have been proved. The constant is irrational [1] and can be computed rapidly [2], [3] with various methods.

[1] Richard André-Jeannin, Irrationalité de la somme des inverses de certaines suites récurrentes, Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des Sciences - Series I - Mathematics 308:19 (1989), pp. 539-541.

[2] Joerg Arndt, On computing the generalized Lambert series, arXiv:1202.6525v3 [math.CA], (2012).

[3] William Gosper, Acceleration of Series, Artificial Intelligence Memo #304 (1974).

Answer (score 2):

It has a closed form formula given by Vladimir Reshetnikov in year $2015$
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{F_n}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\Bigg[\frac{2 \psi _{\frac{1}{\phi ^4}}(1)-4 \psi _{\frac{1}{\phi
   ^2}}(1)+\log (5)}{2 \log (\phi )}+\vartheta _2\left(0,\frac{1}{\phi
   ^2}\right){}^2 \Bigg]$$ where appear  the q-digamma function and the theta function.