# What is a better comparision series for $\sum \frac {1}{F_n}$ than $\sum_0^\infty2^{-k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

What is a better comparision series for $\sum \frac {1}{F_n}$ than $\sum_0^\infty2^{-k}$?

By better comparison series than $\sum_0^\infty2^{-k}$ we mean a series $\sum c_k$ s.t. $\frac{1}{F_k}<c_k<\frac{1}{2^k}$

If possible $\sum c_k$ is a geometric series, or some other well known type of series e.g. $\sum \frac{1}{\alpha2^k}$ for some $\alpha$

By ratio test the sum over Fibonacci numbers converges. Is there a well known series that can be used to bound the value of the sum from above? and/or tighten the upper bound? I am not after closed form for the sum over Fibonacci numbers Just looking for a well known series that can be used for a relatively good comparison (I.e. the series is not way too large).
I am trying to prove $\sum_0^\infty2^{-k}$ can be used for comparison, and then find a better series for comparison.

Comment: See [OEIS A$079586$](http://oeis.org/A079586)

Comment: Thank you @Lucian, how did you find this?

Comment: Google leads also to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51426/reciprocals-of-fibonacci-numbers.  From these you'll find the OEIS reference.  It was found by Googling `sum of the reciprocals of the fibonacci numbers`.

Comment: One choice could be $\sum \tau^{-n}$, or the same thing multiplied by $\sqrt{5}$. Here $\tau=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. This is because of the Binet (?) formula for Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: This question was for a short period closed as a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732155/what-is-the-sum-of-fibonacci-reciprocals) (see also [related discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19321/how-is-a-better-comparison-series-is-a-duplicate-of-the-question-asking-for-the)). Despite the fact that the two questions are not the same, I think that it might be useful to mention link to other question in comments. People interested in this question might also be interested in the other one.

Comment: OP: Please define "comparison series" and "better comparison series".

Comment: Note that $F_{2n}<τ^{2n}/\sqrt5$ and $F_{2n+1}>τ^{2n+1}/\sqrt5$ for every $n$ hence, to compare the sums of the series $∑F_n^{-1}$ and $\sqrt{5}∑τ^{-n}$ requires other arguments than simply the equivalent $F_n\sim\tau^n/\sqrt5$ that Binet provides...

Comment: @Did : modified the question

Comment: Are you aware that $F_k<2^k$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer : now I am. Thank you

Comment: Then you are now aware that $\dfrac{1}{F_k}>\dfrac{1}{2^k}$?  You might want to adjust your goals here.

Comment: @JonasMeyer : Yes, I need to rethink the question

Comment: Starting from $\sqrt5F_n=\tau^n-(-1)^n\tau^{-n}$ with $\tau=\frac12(\sqrt5+1)$, one gets $\sum1/F_n=\sqrt5\sum1/\tau^n+\sqrt5R=2+\tau+\sqrt5R$ where $R=\sum(-1)^n/(\tau^{2n}-(-1)^n)$. The series $R$ is alternated hence one gets explicit lower bounds and/or upper bounds of $\sum1/F_n$, keeping any odd and/or even number of terms in $R$. For example, one and two terms yield $3\lt\sum1/F_n\lt3+\sqrt5/\tau^2$ and $N$ terms yield an approximation of order $1/\tau^{2N}$.