# Sum of inverse of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, fibonacci-numbers

If $F(n)$ is the nth Fibonacci number, How can I prove that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F(i)}\approx 3.36\, .$$

Comment: If all you need to prove is an approximation, you can simply compute the sum of the first $N$ reciprocals. For $N=14$ you get $3.36$.

Comment: @EricS. Unless you estimate the remainder, this proves nothing.

Comment: This may be interesting: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. Hmm, right you are. My bad.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant

Comment: Related: [What is the sum of Fibonacci reciprocals?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732155/what-is-the-sum-of-fibonacci-reciprocals)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but if you really want to show that this is a good approximation, you should probably add ([tag:approximation]) tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
F_n
&=\frac{\phi^n-(-1/\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}\\
&=\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt5}\left(1-\left(-\frac1{\phi^2}\right)^n\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{F_n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt5}{\phi^n}\left(1+\left(-\frac1{\phi^2}\right)^n+\left(-\frac1{\phi^2}\right)^{2n}+\left(-\frac1{\phi^2}\right)^{3n}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\sqrt5\left(\frac1{\phi-1}-\frac1{\phi^3+1}+\frac1{\phi^5-1}-\cdots\right)\\
&=\sqrt5\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\phi^{2k+1}-(-1)^k}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\frac{\sqrt5}{\phi^{19}+1}=0.0002392$,
$$
\sqrt5\sum_{k=0}^8\frac{(-1)^k}{\phi^{2k+1}-(-1)^k}=3.3600587
$$
is less than $0.0002392$ too high.

Comment: It is good approach for approximation of exact value of  this summation. Thanks

Comment: +1 This is one of the good ways how to estimate the error.

Comment: @Amin23 : Yes.  That bound is zero, uniformly in $n$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence

Comment: Is there a bound or function based on parameter $n$ for this approximation $\mid F(n)-\frac{\phi^n-{(-1/\phi)}}{\sqrt{5}} \mid$

Comment: As $n$ gets larger, that error tends to $\frac1{\phi\sqrt5}$, it does not vanish.

Answer (score 8):

Since $F(n) \approx \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt 5}$ for large enough $n$, you may use that as an approximation, which give you a geometric series. For instance, if we use the approximation from the fifth term on, we get
$$
\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \sum_{n = 4}^\infty \frac{\sqrt 5}{\phi^n} \approx 3.3612
$$
To get a feel for how accurate this is, $F(5) = 5$, while $\frac{\phi^5}{\sqrt 5} \approx 4.96$, which is a relative error of less than $1\%$. The relative error gets smaller and smaller as $n$ grows, by a factor of about $3$, and it is alternating (every other term is too large, every other term is too small) which also reduces the error.

Since every term in the sum is less than $1\%$ away from the corresponding term in the original sequence, the true answer is within $1\%$ of the sum we have, which is $\sum_{n = 4}^\infty \frac{\sqrt 5}{\phi^n} \approx 0.53$. Thus the error of this approximation is at most about $0.005$. One more exact term, and the absolute error will be at most $0.001$.

Comment: Thanks for useful comment. Is there a simple analytical method for proofing this summation?

Comment: @Amin23 What do you mean "proofing"? Do you mean calculating $\sum_{n = 5}^\infty \frac{\sqrt 5}{\phi^n}$? Then the answer is "yes", and the exact value is $\frac{\sqrt 5}{\phi^4(\phi - 1)}$. For more details, you can google "sum of convergent geometric series", it will tell you much more than I can tell you in a comment.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The error is less that $1\%$, as I said in my answer (because every term is less than $1\%$ away from the corresponding term in the true sequence), so the absolute error is at most $0.005$. The error of the next term is about $0.3\%$, so if you want better accuracy you can just add more terms.

Comment: @Arthur I find it it's  analytical method in this site   mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html

Comment: @Amin23 If you understand everything on that page (the $q$-polygamma function, the Lambert series and the Jacobi elliptic function), then go ahead. I don't, so I will stick to this.

Comment: @Arthur Just because of these functions that you mentioned I ask you a simple analytical method, But you misunderstanding my meaning.

Comment: @Amin23 So what you really want is not to prove that $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty 1/F(i) \approx 3.36$, but you rather want to _calculate_ the sum $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty 1/F(i)$? Then I have no idea, and that page is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Arthur Ok,Thanks.