# Sum of reciprocals of Fibonacci numbers convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to prove the convergence/divergence of the series´
 $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{F_n} = 1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{8}+...$$
${F_n}$ being the Fibonacci sequence.
The Fibonacci sequence is defined without recursion by:
$${F_n}=\frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} \quad\land\quad\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $$ 
I have tried to prove its convergence with the Root Test and the Ratio Test because of the $n$ exponent but can't manage to do it because of the difference in the fraction.

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Both the root and ratio tests work.

Comment: I'm sure they do, but I'm having problems in the limit calculation because of the difference. If someone could hint me in the right direction it would be great!
Thank you.

Comment: Use the usual trick of pulling out the dominant term: $F_n=\phi^n a_n$ where $a_n\to1/\sqrt5$.

Comment: Thank you so much! The exercises I was doing didn't require much limit calculation techniques and when I tried to prove something on my own I didn't even remember the old tricks!

Comment: Maybe you find the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711292/sum-of-inverse-of-fibonacci-numbers) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$F_{n}=\frac{\phi^{n}-\left(-\phi\right)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$ we have $$F_{n}\sim\frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ so $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{F_{n}}\sim\sqrt{5}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{\phi^{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\phi-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You may prove by induction that for any $n\geq 5$ we have $F_{n+5}\geq 11 F_n$. That is enough to deduce convergence by comparison with a geometric series and further get that:

$$ S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{F_n} =\frac{17}{6}+\sum_{n\geq 5}\frac{1}{F_n} = \frac{17}{6}+\sum_{n=5}^{9}\frac{1}{F_n}+\sum_{n\geq 10}\frac{1}{F_n}\leq \frac{17}{6}+\frac{88913}{185640}+\frac{1}{11}\sum_{n\geq 5}\frac{1}{F_n}$$
such that:
$$ \frac{10}{11}\sum_{n\geq 5}\frac{1}{F_n}\leq \frac{88913}{185640},\qquad S\leq \frac{17}{6}+\frac{11}{10}\cdot \frac{88913}{185640}=\frac{2079281}{618800}. $$

Answer (score 2):

For $n \ge 3$, we have

$$\frac{1}{F_n} \le \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_nF_{n-2}}
= \frac{F_{n} - F_{n-2}}{F_nF_{n-2}} = \frac{1}{F_{n-2}} - \frac{1}{F_n}
= \left(\frac{1}{F_{n-2}} + \frac{1}{F_{n-1}}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{F_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{F_n}\right)\\
= \frac{F_{n}}{F_{n-2}F_{n-1}} - \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n-1}F_n}
$$

The partial sums is monotonic increasing and bounded from above.
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{F_n} = 2 + \sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{F_n}
\le 2 + \frac{F_3}{F_1F_2} - \frac{F_{N+1}}{F_{N-1}F_N} \le 2 + \frac{2}{1\cdot 1} = 4$$
As a result, the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-(-\phi)^{-n-1}}{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}\ge\phi\frac{1-\phi^{-2n-2}}{1+\phi^{-2n}}.$$

The expression on the right is an increasing function of $n$ that exceeds $1$ as of $n=2$ (and quickly tends to $\phi$).

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an interesting proof for the summability of the reciprocals of the FN. It is based on the Kummer's test and the fact that $F_{n-1}\geq  2 F_{n}$, $n\geq 2$. 
First note that $(1/F_n)$ is summable, if and only if, there exists a sequence $(u_n)$ of positive numbers such that 
$$u_n F_{n+1}-u_{n+1}F_{n}\geq F_{n},$$
for all $n$ sufficiently large. (This is the Kummer's test applied to the sequence $(1/F_n)$).
Now, from the definition of FN: $F_{n+1}-F_{n}=F_{n-1}$, for all $n\geq 2$.

That is, taking $u_n = 2$, for all $n\geq 1$, we have that
$2 F_{n+1}- 2 F_{n}= 2 F_{n-1}\geq F_{n}$, for all $n\geq 2$.
As so, by the Kummer's test, the sequence $(1/F_n)$ is summable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_n$ be the fibonacci sequence

We know $F_{2n+2}=F_{2n+1}+F_{2n}\geq 2F_{2n}$

Similarly $F_{2n+1}=F_{2n}+F_{2n-1}\geq 2F_{2n-1}$

So $1/F_2+1/F_4+1/F_6\dots<1/F_2+1/2F_2+1/4F_2\dots=1/F_2(1/2+1/4+1/8\dots)$

$1/F_1+1/F_3+1/F_5\dots<1/F_1+1/2F_1+1/4F_1\dots=1/F_1(1/2+1/4+1/8\dots)$

Now I think it's clearly evident that why the sum of reciprocals of the Fibonacci sequence is convergent, only the definition of the Fibonacci sequence is enough!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$2
\ge \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}
\ge \frac32
$
for $n$ and $n+1$.

Then

$\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}
=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n+1}}+\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}
=1+\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}
\ge 1 + \frac12
=\frac32
$

and

$\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}
=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n+1}}+\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}
=1+\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}
\lt 1 + 1
=2
$.