# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ be the $n^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number. I wanted to  calculate
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{F_n}$$
I simplified it to
$$\sqrt{5}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{\varphi^n-\phi^n}$$
But this didn't seem to help. The value is approximately $3.35988566624317755317201130291892...$. The OEIS entry of this constant is [this](https://oeis.org/A079586). Mathematica gives the answer $$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} \left(\frac{\log 5+2\psi_{\phi^{-4}}(1)-4\psi_{\phi^{-2}}(1)}{2\log\phi}+\vartheta_{2}^{2}\left(\phi^{-2}\right)\right)$$
Where $\vartheta$ is the [Elliptic Theta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticThetaFunction.html) and $\psi$ is the [q-polygamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). This looks very hard to derive. But, this can be calculated, which means that there is surely a method to do this. So, my question is,

> How can the closed form be derived?

If the derivation is very long, an article containing the proof can be mentioned, but a derivation in the answers would be more helpful.

Comment: The WolframMathWorld article contains a derivation: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html. Related questions are https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711292 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732155.

Comment: @player3236 thanks

Comment: You don't need to mess with those special functions, only with $L$ mentioned on mathworld, which up to constants is the weight 2 Eisenstein series $E_2(q)=1-24\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_1(n) q^n$, in contrary to the weights $4,6,8$ it is not a modular form and it doesn't have a closed-form at $a+b\sqrt{-d}$.

Comment: @reuns: $E_2(q)$ has a closed form in terms of values of Gamma functions. Essentially if $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}, n\in\mathbb {N} $ then elliptic modulus $k=k(q) $ is algebraic and the corresponding values of elliptic integrals $E, K$ can be evaluated using Gamma function values (at rational points).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How ? Are you confusing with $E_2(q)-2E_2(q^2)=C \ \theta(q)^2$ ? $E_2\approx \Delta'/\Delta$ so it amounts to get a closed form for $\Delta'$ at CM points which I never heard about, because for $f$ a modular form $E_2f-C f'$ is a modular form it would imply that we know a closed form for all the derivatives of modular forms at CM points.

Comment: @reuns: an example is $E_2(e^{-2\pi})=3/\pi$. But yes you are right that it is a not a modular form. Ramanujan established that for any positive integer $n$ the expression $E_2(q)-nE_2(q^n)$ is a modular form. The closed form for $E_2(q)$ comes from $$E_2(q)=\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^2\left(\frac{6E}{K}+k^2-5\right)$$ and all the values $K, k, E$ can be evaluated in closed form if $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt {n}}, n\in\mathbb {N} $.

Answer (score 1):

$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} }\left({\varphi^n-\phi^n}\right)=\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{5} }\left(1-\left(\frac{\phi }{\varphi }\right)^n\right)$$
$$\frac 1{F_n}=\frac{\sqrt{5} }{\varphi^n} \frac 1{1-\left(\frac{\phi }{\varphi }\right)^n }$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}=\sqrt{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 }{\varphi^n} \frac 1{1-\left(\frac{\phi }{\varphi }\right)^n }=\sqrt{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 }{\varphi^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\phi }{\varphi }\right)^{k n}$$

It is now for the second portion of the summand where the special functions are comming from.

You can have very good *approximations* writing
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}\sim \sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{F_n}+\sqrt{5}\sum_{n=p+1}^{\infty}\frac{1 }{\varphi^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{F_n}+\frac{5+3 \sqrt{5}}{2}  \varphi ^{-(p+1)} $$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{approximation} \\
 5 & 3.35957125458259727076544117389 \\
 10 & 3.35988589577114994666863433486 \\
 15 & 3.35988566607489618438018003508 \\
 20 & 3.35988566624330092650853900324 \\
 25 & 3.35988566624317746272239950104 \\
 30 & 3.35988566624317755323832329939 \\
 35 & 3.35988566624317755317196268711 \\
 40 & 3.35988566624317755317201133856 \\
 45 & 3.35988566624317755317201130289 \\
 50 & 3.35988566624317755317201130292
\end{array}
\right)$$